# SAP Hybris boolean custom facet

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, facet, faceted-search

Add boolean attribute to ProductModel and display it as facet on PLP.

Added new attribute named recipe to ProductModel.
Written populator for it.

```
 - In solr.impex file added below impex
   INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty;solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique=true];name[unique=true];type(code);sortableType(code);currency[default=false];localized[default=false];multiValue[default=false];facet[default=true];facetType(code);useForSpellchecking[default=false];useForAutocomplete[default=false];fieldValueProvider;valueProviderParameter
                             ;$solrIndexedType; recipe  ;boolean;     ;     ;true ;     ;     ;MultiSelectOr ;true;true;springELValueProvider;
```

recipe attribute is coming in solr query as facet.
In backoffice facet is coming as true.

But in frontend I am not able to see facet. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you also added and connected your indexed type to a `SolrSearchQueryProperty`? Try adding this to your impex:

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrSearchQueryProperty; indexedProperty(name, solrIndexedType(identifier))[unique = true]; searchQueryTemplate(name, indexedType(identifier))[unique = true][default = DEFAULT:$solrIndexedType]; facet[default = true]; facetType(code); includeInResponse[default = true]; facetDisplayNameProvider         ; facetSortProvider; facetTopValuesProvider
                                     ; recipe:$solrIndexedType                                    ;                                                                                                      ;                      ; Refine         ;                                  ;                                  ;
```

You can customize the options as you want your facet to work, such as using `Refine`, `MultiSelectOr` or `MultiSelectAnd` for your `facetType(code)` or using your own custom Facet display name or sort providers.

Comment: It worked for me after adding custom value provider.